# trying to combine 'e' as a char and 'x' as string, after combining remove all the letters that are repeated

Tags: haskell

```
testing e x = newstring ([e]++[x])
where newstring [] = []
      newstring [h] = [h]
      newstring (h:t)
         | h `elem` t     = newstring  t
         | otherwise      = h : newstring  t
```

Hi guys, newbie here, may I know what's wrong with my code, I'm trying to combine a character with a string, and check that if there's a letter of 'h' in the tail then remove it.

Comment: If `x` is a string, it is *already* a list; `[e] ++ x` is correct, though `e:x` is much, much better.

Comment: Could you please provide a type signature atop your source code, like `testing :: Char -> String -> String` ?  - to ensure that helpers do not guess it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
testing e x = newstring (e:x)
where newstring [] = []
      newstring [h] = [h]
      newstring (h:t)
         | h `elem` t     = newstring  t
         | otherwise      = [h]++ newstring  t
```

Solved by @chepner

Comment: `[h]++ newstring  t` --> `h : newstring  t`.